# Appkit: tracking rectangles outside visible rect interfere with other views

Tags: appkit, nstrackingarea

Some `NSView` subclasses have tracking rectangles that update the cursor. This is the case for `NSTableHeaderView`, which sets the resizing cursor when the mouse hovers a column separator.

These tracking rectangles show outside the visible rectangle of the view. Typically, an `NSTableHeaderView` is inside an `NSScrollView`. If the clipped part of the table header is behind another view next to it, tracking rectangles cause cursor updates when the mouse is inside this other view. This would disturb the user.

I suppose this is expected behaviour, but I'm surprised that `NSTableHeaderView` (as well as `NSTableView`) doesn't discard tracking rectangles that aren't in the `visibleRect`

What's the best solution to remove these unwanted tracking rectangles? I'm thinking about overriding `-updateTrackingAreas` and removing any tracking area that isn't in the visible rect, after calling `super`. I'm assuming the problematic `NSView` subclasses uses this method to update tracking rectangles.

Comment: It turns out that `NSTableHeaderView` doesn't use `NSTrackingArea` for its cursor rects, but I could achieve what I want by overriding `-addCursorRect:cursor:`. Still, I'd prefer a solution that avoids subclassing.

Comment: I think it's a bug and not expected behaviour. The documentation of `addCursorRect:cursor:` states "You should explicitly confine a cursor rectangle to the view's visible rectangle to prevent improper behavior.". Are the cursor rects where they should be after horizontal scroll?

Comment: Re: "Are the cursor rects where they should be after horizontal scroll?" Yes, they are. Do you think I should file a bug report? Note: this also happens for `NSTableView`. A button inside a cell may have a tracking rectangle, and this rectangle still shows outside the visible rect.